# Angular9 - Return Nested Objects from 2 Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have searched in SO and found similar questions around Observables, but none helped my specific use-case, which, I have to assume is a pretty common use-case.

I am calling a REST API (via the http module) to get a `Quote` object. Naturally it returns an `Observable<Quote>`.

I am also calling another REST API (again via the http module) to get `QuoteLineItem[]`. Again, this naturally returns an `Observable<QuoteLineItem[]>`.

Ideally the client code should only be retrieving `Observable<Quote>` and be able to use Quote.LineItems.

What is the best practice for this? I can come up with two options:

1- Populate Quote.LineItems from the `Observable<QuoteLineItem[]>` when the Observable is subscribed to. I have been trying to get this done, but I don't seem to be doing that. Here is the code, but not sure what is wrong?

```
    // This will change to an http call
    const subj: BehaviorSubject<Quote> = new BehaviorSubject(quote) 
    const obs: Observable<Quote> = subj.asObservable();
    // Now try to get LineItems within the observable and populate Quote.LineItems
    obs.pipe(switchMap((q: Quote) => {
      this.quoteLineItemService.getLineItems(quoteId).subscribe((data: QuoteLineItem[]) => {
        q.lineItems = data
        return q
      },
      error => console.error(error)
      )
    }))
    return obs;
```

This code is getting a compilation error: Argument of type '(q: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.

My first question is, what am I doing wrong here? How can I get that done?

2- Is the above the best practice or should I have `Observable<QuoteLineItem[]>` instead of `QuoteLineItem[]` as a Property within the Quote object?

Sorry if these are very basic questions. Your help, as always would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You may find some inspiration [reading this](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 seems reasonable enough to me. The only issue is the argument type of the callback should be `switchMap((q: Quote)...` with a capital **Q** instead of `switchMap((q: quote)`. Interface/type names are case sensitive. And if I understand correctly, your model is called `Quote` and you have member variable called `quote`. That I believe is the source of the error.

Comment: It actually was a typo as I playing around to try to get it to work. I made that change and I am still getting (thanks for catching, updated the question to reflect this):

Argument of type '(q: Quote) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Quote, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.

Answer (score 0):

The two calls option is not bad at all if you have no access to the backend service you are calling to return a fulfilled model.

To populate you Quote object you can return a Promise of Quote to simplify your code.

Then, make the double request to the server.

```
const getQuote = (id: any): Promise<Quote> => {
    return new Promise<Quote>((resolve, reject) => {
        const obs: Observable<Quote> = subject.asObservable(); // Mocked HTTP call

        obs.subscribe((q: Quote) => {
            quoteLineItemService.getLineItems(q.id).subscribe(
                (items: QuoteLineItem[]) => {
                    q.items = items;
                    resolve(q);
                },
                (err: Error) => {
                    console.error(err);
                    reject(err);
                }
            );
        });
    });
}
```

```
getQuote(1)
    .then((q: Quote) => {
        // Populated quote
        console.log(q);
    })
    .catch(_ => {/* handle error */});
```